# Query sub-classes of Thing by properties inherited from Thing

Tags: java, sparql, jena, schema.org

On the official schema.org documentation, I can see that every class inherits the properties from `Thing` class, for example, the `Book` class also has `name`, `image` etc. (properties from `Thing`).

My question is, can I get for example the `image`(`Thing` property) of every entity(subclass of `Thing`) in a schema.org datastore? For example the `Book` class entities have properties such as `<http://schema.org/Book/image>`, but the `VideoGame` entities have `<http://schema.org/VideoGame/image>`. I want to make a SPARQL query to get the `image` of every entity that contains a certain keyword in its `name` property (which, unfortunately, is again a `Thing` property)

I tried this:

```
String queryString ="select distinct ?graph ?img where {{?a <http://schema.org/name> ?obj. ?a <http://schema.org/image> ?img} union {GRAPH ?graph {?a <http://schema.org/name> ?obj. ?a <http://schema.org/image> ?img }} filter(regex(?obj, \""+keyword+"\",\"i\"))}";
```

```sql
select distinct ?graph ?img where {
  {?a <http://schema.org/name> ?obj.
   ?a <http://schema.org/image> ?img}
  union 
  { GRAPH ?graph {
      ?a <http://schema.org/name> ?obj.
      ?a <http://schema.org/image> ?img
    }
  }
  filter(regex(?obj, \""+keyword+"\",\"i\"))
}
```

altought in the triplestore, `image` properties for `Book` entities have properties such as `<http://schema.org/Book/image>`

The following works, but it's restricted only to Book entities:

```
String queryString ="select distinct ?graph ?img where {{?a <http://schema.org/Book/name> ?obj. ?a <http://schema.org/Book/image> ?img} union {GRAPH ?graph {?a <http://schema.org/Book/name> ?obj. ?a <http://schema.org/Book/image> ?img }} filter(regex(?obj, \""+keyword+"\",\"i\"))}";
```

```sql
select distinct ?graph ?img where {
  { ?a <http://schema.org/Book/name> ?obj.
    ?a <http://schema.org/Book/image> ?img }
  union
  { GRAPH ?graph {
      ?a <http://schema.org/Book/name> ?obj.
      ?a <http://schema.org/Book/image> ?img
    }
  }
  filter(regex(?obj, \""+keyword+"\",\"i\"))
}
```

Does anybody know how can I query by `Thing` properties, regardless of the entity's class (but the entity is still a subclass of `Thing`) ?

Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE**

The triples were provided by Web Data Commons, October 2016 corpus for schema.org (http://webdatacommons.org/structureddata/2016-10/stats/schema_org_subsets.html). More specifically, I took all the *sample*-files and merged them into a triple-store.

Unfortunately, there are errors in this corpus, as @Vladimir and @AKSW pointed out, and the existence of `<http://schema.org/Book/image>` instead of `<http://schema.org/image>` is one of them.

I found on Web Data Common's mailing list similar issues raised by other users. It seems to be a parsing error while extracting metadata.

Thank you for your comments, at least I understood the proper way of querying schema.org annotated triples (when they are valid :) ).

Comment: I don't understand the problem, but I'm not that familiar with SPARQL. From http://schema.org/Book I can see that books also use the same property `http://schema.org/image` to denote images. So from where do you have that a different URI is used per each class?

Comment: The triple-store contains statements like: `<subject> <http://schema.org/Book/image> <object>,` or `<subject> <http://schema.org/VideoGame/image> <object>`. I was also expecting them to be `<http://schema.org/image>`, considering that `image` is inherited from `Thing`...

Comment: Ok, but then the data is not really optimal modelled. and now you want to have all images without restricting to a particular class?

Answer (score 0):

Form my point of view the data then is a bit strange modelled, but you could use the following query although this might be very inefficient:

```sql
SELECT  ?o
WHERE
  { ?s  ?p  ?o
    FILTER strends(str(?p), "/image")
  }
```

It might be a way more efficient to get all properties in a sub-SELECT first, esepcially for more complex queries:

```sql
SELECT  ?o
WHERE
  { # do some other stuff here
    ?s  ?p  ?o
    ...

    # get the image properties here 
    { SELECT DISTINCT  ?p
      WHERE
        { ?s  ?p  ?o
          FILTER strends(str(?p), "/image")
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the first approach. Indeed, the triple store contains some invalid statements (I added an update to my question), but your solution works if I want to get over the mistakes and get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Which triple store do you mean? Schema does not have the property URLs you mention. Fix that data (or ask whoever made it, to fix it)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I searched more and indeed some of the triples are not valid. I added an update to my question